# Root has taken rights

Tags: mount, permissions, root

I installed root user of Ubuntu and it is working properly. But the only problem is when I come back to my main account, it says that I cannot unmount or mount any drive, as it's in root's ownership. I tried going into root and changing owner from there but when I change back it reverts quickly.

Please help as I've to go to root every time when I want to mount or unmount something

Thank You

EDIT:

Here is the content of `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

proc    /proc   proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda8 :
UUID=f406231f-88c0-4bcc-8f71-84f962ed0306   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
#Entry for /dev/sda6 :
UUID=5CFA3E3AFA3E112E   /media/Games    ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda3 :
UUID=AC7C4EC27C4E86D4   /media/OS   ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda2 :
UUID=CC70378A703779F2   /media/Recovery ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=E6D61DB1D61D834B   /media/Storage  ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0   0
#Entry for /dev/sda7 :
UUID=5e23a31f-95c8-4d0b-ab6c-d34e83fa3a23   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I installed root user"?

Comment: I mean like, enabled root user. You know, like going to Terminal, and doing sudo passwd and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use command with `users` option

```
sudo mount -o users /dev/sdXY /mountpoint
```

The `users` option gives rights to (un)mount for everybody.

The device node is a special device pseudo-file inside `/dev` directory. You can find information about your Storage's device node in Disks utility. X and Y are drive letter and partition number respectively.

[image]

You should modify your `/etc/fstab` file to make the changes permanent. Use `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`, find the line with `/media/Storage` and add `users` option to the 4th column:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

proc    /proc   proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid     0       0
#Entry for /dev/sda8 :
UUID=f406231f-88c0-4bcc-8f71-84f962ed0306       /       ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
#Entry for /dev/sda6 :
UUID=5CFA3E3AFA3E112E   /media/Games    ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8     0       0
#Entry for /dev/sda3 :
UUID=AC7C4EC27C4E86D4   /media/OS       ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8     0       0
#Entry for /dev/sda2 :
UUID=CC70378A703779F2   /media/Recovery ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8     0       0
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=E6D61DB1D61D834B   /media/Storage  ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8,users     0       0
#Entry for /dev/sda7 :
UUID=5e23a31f-95c8-4d0b-ab6c-d34e83fa3a23       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Then, you can mount/unmount this drive using

```
mount /media/Storage      #mount Storage
umount /media/Storage    #unmount Storage
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting fast, but it says "special device /device/node does not exist" Sorry Im completely new to it and I know nothing.

By the way, The device I want to mount is named "Storage". 

Thank You

Comment: The device node is a special device file inside `/dev` directory. You can find information about your Storage's device node in Disks utility.

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: It still saying the same, only root can unmount or mount

https://flic.kr/p/mu2Jex

Comment: How did you mount the drive?

Comment: When I (re)boot and come into Ubuntu all the files are already mounted. I have to go to root to unmount all. Then If i want to mount I again have to go to root and mount there. and the command

sudo mount -o users /device/node /mountpoint only worked for mounting, if i click "unmount device" it says "Only root can unmount".

Comment: Please specify exact command: it should be `sudo mount -o users /dev/sdXY /mnt/Storage` where X and Y are drive letter and partition number respectively.

Comment: It is sudo mount -o users /dev/sda1 /media/Storage That is what I type and it mounted. But I cannot unmount though.

Comment: Add this option inside your `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: ... I'm sorry, I don't understand how to "add" that. Could explain in detail please. Sorry. Thank for helping though.

Comment: See the updated answer. You should find the line with `/media/Storage` and modify the 4th column as shown.

Comment: I really don't understand. I'm completely noob. Can you show step-by-step in pictures (Like you've shown earlier) in a new post. If not, thanks alot for your assistance till now. Thank you :)

Comment: Just attach your `/etc/fstab` file inside your question and I'll show you what lines should be changed.

Comment: Ok, i've updated and added /etc/fstab in my question.

Comment: I updated my answer. Don't forget to use `sudo` when you edit `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Mount worked, it says " unmount : command not found". Also, I wanted to mount it the old way. You know pressing on Storage will mount it, and to unmount right click and press unmount kinda way. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it's the `umount` actually. You should now be able to (un)mount disk the standard way. If it does not work, just remove or comment out line with `/media/Storage`. It will then be mounted inside `/media/username/Storage`, but you will be able to mount it and unmount.

Comment: Woah! Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm. Thanks for staying with me and helping me out. :D!

Comment: You're welcome, my friend.